# How to refresh code without losing scroll position?

Tags: javascript

I am using the script to reload the page every 10 seconds. I want to retain the scroll position even after the refresh. The following is my script:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  var idleInterval = setInterval("reloadPage()", 10000);

  function reloadPage() {
    location.reload(false);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: There is no need for an interval since this will only run once. Also, the fact that you need to refresh the page every x seconds sounds like bad design of a function that could be done with ajax.

Answer (score 10):

you can do something like this :

```
window.addEventListener('scroll',function() {
    //When scroll change, you save it on localStorage.
    localStorage.setItem('scrollPosition',window.scrollY);
},false);
```

then on load :

```
window.addEventListener('load',function() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition') !== null)
       window.scrollTo(0, localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition'));
},false);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use session storage to store the position then get back to the position when the page is reloaded, like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  sessionStorage.scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  if (sessionStorage.scrollTop != "undefined") {
    $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollTop);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store the position on the user's `localStorage` before reloading and getting it when you open the page.

```js
window.scrollTo(localStorage.scrollPos || 0, 0);

setTimeout(function(){
  //Saves the current scroll position before reloading the page.
  localStorage.setItem('scrollPos', window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop);
  location.reload();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: you can also add scrollPosition on url by anchor instead of stored on localStorage. Like this you can share url and keep last scroll position. Nice approch

Comment: Yeah that's one way but the url should be kept clean when possible. The user wouldn't understand what's going on with that random number up there.

Comment: yes is true, let keep localStorage do the job. Happy coding @Phiter